# Determine PS3 using Flash system capabilities

Tags: linux, flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone know if is it possible to distinguish between Linux and PS3 using System Capabilities? or any other method for that matter.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Capabilities.Version wil show the OS before the Flash version, Win, Mac, Lin, And, PS3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/PlayStation%203/), PlayStation has special useragent, you could check for navigator.userAgent.indexOf("PLAYSTATION") > -1.

Comment: Thanks, that's one way to do it but I wanted to within Flash so used the solution below.